# .Net Multitargeting with Single File Exe

Tags: c#, .net

I need to distribute a single file `exe` built in .Net 3.5 (i.e. 2.0) but that will also run on .Net 4.x.

The executable runs fine without prompting to install .Net if the `Foo.exe.config` file is there specifying the `<supportedRuntime>`. But without that file, it asks to install .Net 3.5 (if it's not already installed).

Is there any way to specify the supported runtimes within the `exe` file, without a `.config` file? Or is there some other way to bootstrap the app into whatever runtime is available?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to do so. I've came across [this](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/) article - it is about `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` but you might want to give it a look.